# Ifconfig report some interfaces with strange names on MacOS

Tags: macos, ifconfig

The command

```
ifconfig
```

Report some strange interfaces on MacOS

```
OHC6: flags=0<> mtu 0
OHC4: flags=0<> mtu 0
EHC36: flags=0<> mtu 0
EHC38: flags=0<> mtu 0
```

What is OHC and EHC?

Comment: It may be an abbreviation for the USB host controller interfaces [OHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Open_Host_Controller_Interface_2) and [EHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Enhanced_Host_Controller_Interface). Check it against the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: lsusb: command not found

Comment: see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332191/surprisingly-many-network-interfaces-on-macos-are-these-legitimate

Comment: Sure they are usb interface, add this as answer please, so I can vote and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might be USB interface... ([OHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Open_Host_Controller_Interface_2) and [EHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Enhanced_Host_Controller_Interface))

Comment: Please refer this link https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer , will help you to compaose good answer !!